# Repetición de pronombres átonos en frases con verbos pronominales

Tags: pronombres

Ya sé que frases como las siguientes son incorrectas por la repetición de pronombres:

> Se lo tengo que decírselo.

> Se debe respetarse cualquier opinión.

Pero en el caso de una frase que contiene un verbo pronominal, como en la siguiente frase:

> Nos dejaron marcharnos.

El primer pronombre es imprescindible pues `Dejaron marcharnos.` es incorrecta, y el segundo me parece imprescindible también por formar parte del verbo `marcharse`, aunque el contexto permita entender el sentido de `Nos dejaron marchar.`

¿Qué pensáis al respecto? Llevo unas horas buscando informaciones sobre este asunto en la Nueva Gramática sin éxito, así que ojalá podáis ayudarme a aclaralo!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La oración:

- **Nos** dejaron marchar**nos** (= Nos dejaron irnos)

es correcta porque cada pronombre desempeña una función diferente: el primer "nos" es complemento directo y el segundo "nos" es marca de verbo pronominal.

Así, la oración:

- **Nos** dejaron marchar.

podría interpretarse como:

- Nos permitieron formar parte del desfile militar.

Del mismo modo, la oración:

- **Nos** permitieron ir.

podría interpretarse como "nos permitieron ir (a un determinado lugar)" y no como "nos permitieron irnos (de donde estábamos)".

Answer (score 1):

No sé si será posible encontrar una referencia en la NGLE sobre este asunto y, en vista de que ya estuviste buscando ahí durante horas sin éxito, no voy a intentarlo. Para mí la respuesta es que ambos pronombres en principio son gramaticalmente necesarios (aun cuando el resultado parezca redundante y suene mal) porque pertenecen a dos verbos diferentes.

El primer *nos* es el complemento indirecto de *dejaron*, con un uso común a otros verbos similares (sinónimos y antónimos): *[a nosotros] nos dejaron, nos permitieron, nos prohibieron, nos negaron [el permiso de]*, etc. El segundo *nos* es el pronombre que requiere el verbo *marchar*.

En este caso, como en muchos otros, existe una versión no pronominal con el mismo significado, o uno muy similar, de manera que el pronombre parece opcional. No hay muchas situaciones realistas en las que la presencia o ausencia del pronombre cambiaría el significado o siquiera causaría una ambigüedad. *Nos prohibieron acordar* significa "nos negaron permiso para llegar a un acuerdo" pero *nos prohibieron acordarnos* es "nos prohibieron recordar". **Esto no significa que el segundo pronombre sea gramaticalmente opcional; significa que lo es, casi siempre, pragmáticamente.**