# Pregunta sobre uso de pronombres en "dejarse enredar en"

Tags: gramática, objetos-directos, verbo-pronominal, clíticos

Del libro *El arte de no amargarse la vida* (España):

> Probablemente, lo mejor sea no dejar**se** enredar en terribilizaciones y seguir con nuestra vida.

Quisiera comprobarme a mí mismo. ¿Es correcto decir que lógicamente tendría que ser como "*no dejar**se** enredar**se** en*"? ¿Pero es común omitir uno de los mismos pronombres para que no se dupliquen (cacafonía)? ¿Y después de omitir uno de pronombres "*se*" solo podemos decir como "*no dejar**se** enredar*", pero no "*no dejar enredar**se***"? Tal como en esta cadena [Dejarte irte, dejarte ir, dejar irte](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/q/32024/23475).

Comment: muy buena pregunta. No se me ocurre cómo titularla para que se encuentre mejor en el futuro, así que me limito a etiquetas y formato

Answer (score 3, accepted):

La frase problemática es “dejarse enredar”. Esta es una frase no finita, es decir, una frase con un verbo principal no conjugado (en este caso, un verbo en infinitivo); este verbo principal es *dejarse*.

Podemos probar conjugando el verbo para ver cómo se comporta: “Él se deja enredar (en...)”. El sujeto se permite a sí mismo sufrir la acción de una tercera persona: “Él deja que (alguien) lo enrede (en...)” o bien “Él se permite ser enredado (en...) (por alguien)”.

El verbo *enredar* no es reflexivo en este caso, porque el sujeto de *dejarse* no es el sujeto de *enredar*. El sujeto implícito de *dejarse* es el **objeto directo** implícito de *enredar*.

Podemos decir “Él se deja enredar” o bien “Él se enreda (por sí mismo)”, pero ésas son dos cosas totalmente opuestas, y no pueden aparecer en la misma frase. Por eso las opciones son “dejarse enredar” (reflexiva y semánticamente pasiva) o bien “enredarse” (reflexiva y semánticamente activa).

Answer (score 2):

En la oración:

> Probablemente, lo mejor sea no dejarse enredar en terribilizaciones y seguir con nuestra vida.

el pronombre enclítico "se" tiene valor reflexivo, y puede añadirse a "dejar" o a "enredar". Su duplicación resultaría en una redundancia:

- Lo mejor es no dejar**se** enredar.
- Lo mejor es no dejar enredar**se**.

Con "dejar" conjugado, tendríamos:

- **Me** dejé enredar.
- Dejé enredar**me**.

A diferencia de la [otra pregunta](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/32024/dejarte-irte-dejarte-ir-dejar-irte) mencionada o de [esta otra](https://spanish.stackexchange.com/questions/35001/repetici%C3%B3n-de-pronombres-%C3%A1tonos-en-frases-con-verbos-pronominales/35002#35002) relacionada, donde el verbo en infinitivo cambia de significado según sea o no pronominal, en el caso de "enredar" sólo cabe la posibilidad de que ese verbo sea reflexivo: hay por lo tanto un solo pronombre que puede combinarse con el propio "enredar" o, en este caso, con el verbo "dejar".

Para que haya una correcta duplicación de pronombres, el pronombre debe ser requerido por ambos verbos por separado, por ejemplo:

- **Me** filmé enredándo**me** con el ovillo de lana.

(En este caso, hay dos verbos en reflexivo: *filmarse* y *enredarse*, y por lo tanto son necesarios los dos pronombres.)